# How to call Activity class method in inner class method in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, inner-classes

I have create one progress method in Activity class. then create one another class for AsyncTask.

My requirement is call **processProgressBar()** method in AsyncTask class doInBackground()

How it possible?

**See My Code:**

```
package com.example.bharat.generalknowledge

import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import com.example.bharat.generalknowledge.dbhandler.DatabaseHandler
import org.xml.sax.InputSource
import java.io.BufferedInputStream
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.net.URL
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream

class WelcomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    init {
        println("Init block")
    }

    companion object {
        var dbPath: String = ""
        var isDatabaseExist: Boolean = false
        private val handler = Handler()
        val wActivity = WelcomeActivity()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome)

        val dbHandler = DatabaseHandler(this)
        isDatabaseExist = dbHandler.checkIfTableExistOrNot()
        Log.w("isDatabaseExist: ", isDatabaseExist.toString())
        if(!isDatabaseExist){
            dbPath = dbHandler.getDatabasePath()
            downloadDb().execute()
        }
    }

    fun processProgressBar(pStatus: Int=10){

        println("====================processProgressBar==========================")
        val res = resources
        val drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.circular)
        val mProgress = findViewById<View>(R.id.circularProgressbar) as ProgressBar
        mProgress.progress = 0   // Main Progress
        mProgress.secondaryProgress = 100 // Secondary Progress
        mProgress.max = 100 // Maximum Progress
        mProgress.progressDrawable = drawable
        mProgress.progress = pStatus
    }

    class downloadDb() : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): String? {
            try {
                // download the file
                val url = URL("http://192.168.0.105/new-gk-app/web/uploads/db-backup/gk_app.gz")
                val connection = url.openConnection()
                connection.connect()

                // get stream and convert gzip to db original
                var stream = connection.getInputStream()
                stream = GZIPInputStream(stream)
                val `is` = InputSource(stream)

                val input = BufferedInputStream(`is`.byteStream, 8192)
                val output = FileOutputStream(dbPath)

                val data = ByteArray(1024)
                while ((input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    output.write(data);

                    // processProgressBar(30)  /* ****** my requirement is call this method ******* */
                }
                output.flush()
                output.close()
                input.close()

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.message)
            }
            return null
        }

        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()
            Log.w("Database Downloded: ", "Start")
            // ...
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            Log.w("Database Downloded: ", "Finish")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the reference of your activity in the constructor of your Async task, wrapped in a weak reference and call your function from there.

```
 class downloadDb(var activity:WeakReference<WelcomeActivity >) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>()
```

and in you `doInBackground`

```
  activity.get()?.let {
                it.runOnUiThread({

                })
            }
```

To initialise the AysncTask,`downloadDb(WeakReference(this))`

Comment: i don't understand your answer

Comment: You just need to pass the reference of your activity to the async task. Its just like sending an object, but I have used weakReference so that there are no memory leaks.